# Set the <head> and <body> from the same eex file

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

In a particular new website using Elixir and Phoenix, there is lots of boilerplate in order to make the pages have a consistent style. Hence there is a "layout" template whose `inner_content` delegation is inside the html `<body>` tag (and a couple `<div>`s for styling). However, some parts of the `<head>` actually do change page-to-page, and these aren't just a few trivial values like the `<title/>`, there's a bunch of SEO metadata too.

Worse yet, there's probably enough visible boilerplate in each page, that significant nontrivial parts of the `<body>` probably ought to be factored out of the individual templates and into the layout, yet those parts might also contain title-like values.

How do I specify arbitrary extra content for the `<head>`, or for other places outside the one place where the vast majority of page-to-page-variable content goes, without getting an unmaintainable anti-DRY mess? (Where I come from, a child template could divide itself up into multiple named blocks that a layout template could substitute by-name at multiple different places within itself.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct thing to do is to use `assigns` field on the `[Plug.Conn][1]`

In my Pheonix (v 1.6.10) there's pre-decided `page_title` assigns, so just do this:

```
conn
|> assign(:page_title), "My Special title")
```

and it just works, because my `root.html.heex` has this:

```
<%= live_title_tag assigns[:page_title] || "Rumbl", suffix: " · Phoenix Framework" %>
```

And I suppose this is the right thing to do with any other custom stuff, like SEO medatada:

```
conn
|> assign(:my_seo_metadata), "Whatever")
```

and add in your template

```
<whatever>
<%= assigns[:my_seo_metadata] %>
</whatever>
```

Comment: So to be clear, you're saying that intermingling textual wording into the view code, rather than the textual wording being in the same template file with the textual wording it describes, is S.O.P. with Phoenix?

I'm concerned about the ability to let a less-technical person loose on GitHub's "Fork and Edit" button so they can make wording changes, simple or not, (even if the wording is actually somewhere in the `<head>`) which by definition needn't consume a more-technical person's time (except basic sanity-checking that it really is just a wording change). That can be doable with Django.

Comment: You can fetch this value from a DB, or wherever you want. Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I thought you had trouble getting this info in the template? In general - you're not supposed to set it from the EEX file, the controller should be a better place for that.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to accomplish is shown in the two code examples "Base Template" and "Child Template" at https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#template-inheritance - the template for each specific page is divided into multiple parts and each part goes into a different place of the site's layout template. I guess it needs to be a feature-request on the elixir repo?